# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

these are the commands i executed in the terminal

```
pip install --upgrade selenium

wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.23.0/geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz

tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

output-geckodriver

```
rm geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz

chmod +x geckodriver

cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

output-cp:

> cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver': Permission denied

Comment: If your error is `cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'` why is the question heading `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. firefox`?

Comment: @DebanjanB That was the error I was facing first, after trying this method I ended up here. Since I am new to python I didn't know it was the right method to approach the first problem

Comment: Did you try `sudo cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin/`?

Comment: Thankyou, it worked @Andersson

Comment: @Praveen note that even if file was copied you might need to change file owner (with `chown` command) to be able to use file correctly